# Install Trust Bundle Certificate on Android without Root or Warnings

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, root, pki

I am having the most difficult time figuring out how to get a cell phone that will trust my local domain certificates without being very difficult or expensive.

Android devices tested up to 8.0 give a warning like: "Certificate authority installed by an unknown third party" or "Network May Be Monitored" on boot.

Is it possible to remove this message without rooting the phone?  I need to set up always on VPN and SIP calling for the local pbx along with internal web sites.  Android is the only offering with a native SIP client.  But the warning causes too much trouble =/

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Android 8.

First transfer copy of the cert file to phone.

If using mkcert, the file location is found via CLI: mkcert -CAROOT

Then install the cert file in Android settings, the location of which varies per device and Android version.

In my phone it was in: Android Settings / General / Lock screen & security / Encryption & credentials / Install from storage

You might have to restart the phone. Also might have to click TRUST on the cert in Android settings.

Then enable Firefox secret settings by tapping multiple times on the Firefox logo in the About page, then in secret settings enable "Use third party CA certificates".

Voila!